# Menu expandable on hover in angular.js

Tags: css, angularjs, menu

I have problem with expandable and collapsible menu on mouse hover, I have code like this:

**html**:

```
  <div ng-mouseout="showMenu=false" class="dashboard-menu">
      <div ng-show="showMenu" class="sub-menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a class="lighting"><span>Add an action</span><span class="icon"></span></a></li>
          <li><a class="html"><span>Add HTML/JS</span><span class="icon"></span></a></li>
          <li><a class="image"><span>Add an image</span><span class="icon"></span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div ng-mouseover="showMenu=true"><span class="icon plus"></span></div>
    </div>
```

**css**:

```
.icon {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #000;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.plus {
  float: right;
}
.dashboard-menu {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

why menu hide when I'm out of .plus icon? How to fix it? Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/zPaqcmWOxo1g5LCI6DjD?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

I was also able to get your code working by adding the `ng-mouseover="showMenu=true"` to the dashboard-menu div.

```
<body ng-app>
    <div class="dashboard-menu" ng-mouseover="showMenu=true" ng-mouseout="showMenu=false">
      <div ng-show="showMenu" class="sub-menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a class="lighting"><span>Add an action</span><span class="icon"></span></a></li>
          <li><a class="html"><span>Add HTML/JS</span><span class="icon"></span></a></li>
          <li><a class="image"><span>Add an image</span><span class="icon"></span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div ng-mouseover="showMenu=true"><span class="icon plus"></span></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: "showmenu=true" works but then, i dont know why you would want a menu to stick there, when the intention is for it to autohide, I dont really see what this guy is asking

Comment: @Ricky He was having trouble with the menu auto hiding before anything could be done due to the fact that the menu would hid as soon as the mouse left the button to show the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ng-mouseleave` fixed the issue.